# chroot: can't execute /init.sh: Permission denied - Error while want to start linux on Android

Tags: linux, permissions, shell, busybox

**Introduction:**

I formatted a SDCard in ext4 and copied an ArchVersion on it to run it from Android like in this [guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mDYfvXy5NoDCWgHkIhm0VKyrDi6eYzUIXotxiWCxoG4/edit?pref=2&pli=1) (step 7). Of course my device is rooted and I am running the following scripts and commands in the *Terminal Emulator* as superuser.

Device-info:

- Phone: Sony Xperia Z1
- Model number: C6903
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Build Number: 14.6.A.1.236

**Issue:**

After executing `sh storage/emulated/0/linux/linux.sh 2> storage/emulated/0/linux/output.txt`the device ends up in Android again because the command `chroot /data/local/mnt /init.sh` **can't execute /init.sh: Permission denied**.

**linux.sh**:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

export LINUXROOT=/data/local/mnt
export TMPDIR=/tmp
export HOME=/root
export USER=root
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:$PATH
export TERM=vt100


sh ./mount.sh # works fine
sh ./stopandroid.sh # works fine

echo "******* Your chroot-environment is starting now ********"
chroot $LINUXROOT /init.sh # can't execute /init.sh: Permission denied
echo "******* You exited the chroot-environment, unmounting... ********"

sh ./umount.sh
sh ./startandroid.sh

echo " ## DONE"
```

I already found some posts about this issue together with [LinuxonAndroid](http://linuxonandroid.org/what-is-linuxonandroid/) and [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=de). I do not use LinuxonAndroid and installed BusyBox from *Google Play Store* which should solve the problem when running another BusyBox-version what I do not.

Like it is stated [here](http://www.robherc.com/hosted/linuxonandroid/FAQ.html) it may require to `chmod 0755 /data/data/com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid/files/busybox` which is not possible in my case, because obviously the folder `com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid` does not exist.

So I searched for **busybox** inside `/data/data`, found one file and changed permission: `chmod 0777 data/data/stericson.busybox/files/bb/busybox`.

I also changed the permissions of **init.sh**: `chmod 777 init.sh`

I also tried to run the command `chroot /data/local/mnt /init.sh` in the terminal with the same result.

After these changes I really do not have a clue whats wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at how the card was mounted. Usually, SD cards are mounted with the `noexec` option, which means exactly that: not giving the permission to execute stuff.

Comment: I added `exec` to the mount command: `mount -t ext4 -o noatime,rw,exec /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 $LINUXROOT` but it does not change the result, but I added another `test.sh` and `chroot` with it, also getting the **permission denied** error. But `sh test.sh` works, so I can execute but not inside the `chroot` command.

Comment: have you checked with e.g. `mount | grep mmcblk1p2` whether the flag was accepted?

Comment: I executed `mount | grep mmcblk1p2` and `exec` is not part of the flags, so how do I get it mounted with `exec` accepted? And why can I execute a normal `.sh`-file if `exec` is not accepted?

Comment: I don't know what mechanism overwrites that. Does it still list the `noexec` flag?

Comment: No it does not... -> output: `/dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/local/mnt ext4 rw,seclabel,noatime,data=ordered 0 0`